# Python parser.parse combined with if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, if-statement

I am working on a calculator project, I am using yacc as a parser and as I have 4 different values to parse I wanted to check what was just parsed.
I have a strong feeling it won't work but I don't know what to use else.
I Only get this error message: `Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)`

If anyone can help me, I would very much appreciate it.

This is my code, the piece of code I'm talking about would be:

```
if parser.parse(C1):
t[0] = float(C1)
MwGCalc.MwGCalc(C1)
```

MwGCalc is this right here, it currently only works for 4*4 but it's just for testing purposes and not very well thought out:

```
print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
import numpy as np
import cgitb
import cgi

cgitb.enable()
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
C1 = form.getvalue('C1')
# Defining Variables

#Actual Calculating
if C1 == 256:
    p = C1
    print(p)
```

And this right here is the Code for the calculator:

````
import numpy as np
import MwGCalc
#!C:\Users\Letsmoe\Anaconda3\python.exe
print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
tokens = (
    'NAME', 'NUMBER',
    'PLUS', 'MINUS', 'TIMES', 'DIVIDE', 'EQUALS',
    'LPAREN', 'RPAREN', 'POWER', 'FUNC',
)

# Tokens

t_PLUS = r'\+'
t_MINUS = r'-'
t_TIMES = r'\*'
t_DIVIDE = r'/'
t_EQUALS = r'='
t_LPAREN = r'\('
t_RPAREN = r'\)'
t_NAME = r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'
t_POWER = r'\^'
t_FUNC = r'(sin)|(cos)|(tan)|(ln)|(log)|(sqrt)'


def t_NUMBER(t):
    r'\d+'  # [0-9]+
    try:
        t.value = int(t.value)
    except ValueError:
        print("Integer value too large %d", t.value)
        t.value = 0
    return t


# Ignored characters
t_ignore = r" \t\r"


def t_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += t.value.count("\n")


def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)


# Build the lexer

lexer = lex.lex()

# Parsing rules

precedence = (
    ('left', 'PLUS', 'MINUS'),
    ('left', 'TIMES', 'DIVIDE'),
    ('left', 'POWER'),
    ('right', 'UMINUS'),
)

# dictionary of names
names = {}


def p_statement_assign(t):
    'statement : NAME EQUALS expression'
    names[t[1]] = t[3]


def p_statement_expr(t):
    'statement : expression'
    if parser.parse(C1):
        t[0] = float(C1)
        MwGCalc.MwgCalc(C1)


def p_expression_binop(t):
    '''expression : expression PLUS expression
                  | expression MINUS expression
                  | expression TIMES expression
                  | expression DIVIDE expression
                  | expression POWER expression'''
    if t[2] == '*':
        t[0] = t[3]**t[1]


def p_expression_uminus(t):
    'expression : MINUS expression %prec UMINUS'
    t[0] = -t[2]


def p_expression_func(t):
    'expression : FUNC LPAREN expression RPAREN'
    if t[1] == 'sin':
        t[0] = np.sin(t[3])
    elif t[1] == 'cos':
        t[0] = np.cos(t[3])
    elif t[1] == 'log':
        t[0] = (np.log(t[3])) / (np.log(10))
    elif t[1] == 'sqrt':
        t[0] = np.sqrt(t[3])
    elif t[1] == 'ln':
        t[0] = (np.log(t[3]))


def p_expression_group(t):
    'expression : LPAREN expression RPAREN'
    t[0] = t[2]


def p_expression_number(t):
    'expression : NUMBER'
    t[0] = t[1]


def p_expression_name(t):
    'expression : NAME'
    try:
        t[0] = names[t[1]]
    except LookupError:
        print("Undefined name '%s'" % t[1])
        t[0] = 0


def p_error(t):
    print("Syntax error at '%s'" % t.value)


if __name__ == "__main__":  # HTML is following
    print()  # blank line, end of headers
    print("<TITLE>CGI script output</TITLE>")

    import ply.yacc as yacc

    parser = yacc.yacc()
    # while True:
    #    try:
    #        s = input('calc > ')   # Use raw_input on Python 2
    #    except EOFError:
    #          break
    #    parser.parse(s)

    import cgi
    import cgitb

    cgitb.enable()
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    C1 = form.getvalue('C1')
    if C1 is not None:
        C1 = str(C1)
    C2 = form.getvalue('C2')
    if C2 is not None:
        C2 = str(C2)
    C3 = form.getvalue('C3')
    if C3 is not None:
        C3 = str(C3)
    C4 = form.getvalue('C4')
    if C4 is not None:
        C4 = str(C4)

    for C1 in C1.splitlines():
        parser.parse(C1)
    for C2 in C2.splitlines():
        parser.parse(C2)
    for C3 in C3.splitlines():
        parser.parse(C3)
    for C4 in C4.splitlines():
        parser.parse(C4)```
````

Comment: Added MwGCalc, sorry for not adding it before.

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. This is not minimal. For example, you should be able to test the parsing part of the problem without the HTML part. There is too much going on with the code. Can you cut it down to something which shows the core problem? I do find it odd that your parsing rules are not recursive and you seem to be trying to use exponentiation to evaluate multiplication.

Comment: Well, basically I want to check which variable my parser was just parsing and then to give the parsing result to the next script, the only thing I'd need to know is how "if parser.parse('C1'):" is written correctly, I know it won't work with that. Also as you said using Times for Power seems not very smart but it's currently just meant as a prototype.

Comment: You seem to expect that `parser.parse(C1)` returns a boolean (it doesn't, in general), and that it somehow magically changes the value of `C1` (it can't) in a way that makes it possible for `float(C1)` to return something meaningful (also not possible). In short, your code shows very little understanding of the Python programming language, which is a prerequisite for understanding how to use a Python package like Ply. I hope that didn't sound too harsh. But the multiple layers of misunderstanding make it difficult to find a question which can reasonably be answered.

Comment: As a first step, the `parser.parse` function takes a string as an argument and *returns* the result of the parse. There is no definition of what the "result of the parse" is; that's basically up to you, since it will be the semantic value placed in p[0] by the top-level symbol's semantic action. (I understand that that might sound like greek to you, but it's hard to condense parsing theory into a SO comment.) Regardless, you will almost always want to save the value returned by `parser.parse` since the point of parsing is to turn an input text into some value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now found a solution to the issue, it's definitely not perfect but fits my needs.
Here's the code:

```
def p_statement_expr(t):
    """statement : expression"""
    if line is not None:
        MwGCalc.Calc2(float(t[1]))
    if five is not None:
        MwGCalc.Calc(float(t[1]))
```

In my MwGCalc script I check for inputs of those two values: five and line

They are both non-important variables, you can name them however you prefer, but if you do so you will have to change them here aswell:

```
if s is not None:
    for line in s.splitlines ():
        parser.parse ( line )
        line = None
if d is not None:
    for five in d.splitlines ():
        parser.parse ( five )
        five = None
```

Be sure you don't forget to set both values to None after parsing because it might lead to the first one to appear both times because it's still defined and in use.
By changing those values the MwGCalc script can now check by using this code:

```
def Calc2(t):
    print ( 'Whatup', t )


def Calc(t):
    print ( 'Hi', t )
```

It defines those variables which I use in my first script, which then refers to them.
Then it can be used for further processing by assigning the float value t to another variable which is then used by me for calculating some stuff.

Be sure to don't use 't[1]' because it can't be subscripted after sending to the other script, it will just be 't'.

Here's my script output when using '4 by 4' for s and '4 by 5' for d:

```
Whatup 16.0
Hi 20.0
```

Hope it might help someone, helped me a lot.

Have a nice day.